# XSLT multiple output: copy selected nodes and the rest too

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <extras>
      <extra>
         <model>Z1</model>
      </extra>
      <extra>
         <model>Z2</model>
      </extra>
      <extra>
         <model>X</model>
      </extra>
   </extras>
   <color>red</color>
   <tire>goodyear</tire>
</car>
```

I'm trying to generate one output xml for each `<extra>..</extra>` element in a way that the resulting xmls should contain all the elements from the input but only one particular `<extra>` element.
I.e, the resulting outputs should be:

extra1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <extras>
      <extra>
         <model>Z1</model>
      </extra>
   </extras>
   <color>red</color>
   <tire>goodyear</tire>
</car>
```

extra2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <extras>
      <extra>
         <model>Z2</model>
      </extra>
   </extras>
   <color>red</color>
   <tire>goodyear</tire>
</car>
```

extra3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <extras>
      <extra>
         <model>X</model>
      </extra>
   </extras>
   <color>red</color>
   <tire>goodyear</tire>
</car>
```

I'm using  from XSLT 2.0 Saxon-HE 9.6.0-5.

My xslt looks like as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template name="full">
        <xsl:param name="enode" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/">
            <xsl:if test="*[not($enode = current())]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="extras">
        <xsl:for-each select="//extra">
            <xsl:result-document href="extra{position()}.xml">
                <xsl:call-template name="full">
                    <xsl:with-param name="enode" select="current()" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <extras>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()" />
                </extras>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm able to generate the output xmls which only contain one `<extra>` element, but how to copy the rest of the elements from the input (i.e:
all elements except children of `<extras>`?)
I tried to create a template "full" which loops through all the nodes and copies only those that are different than the node I'm passing as a parameter (enode), but no success. 
Is there any (other) way to obtain the desired result?
If the order of the elements in the resulting xml is different what I provided is not a problem, I can rearrange them in a second pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't it be simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/car">
    <xsl:for-each select="extras/extra">
        <xsl:result-document href="extra{position()}.xml">
            <car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <extras>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                </extras>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../../(* except extras)"/>
            </car>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```